# Object pushed into array nested within another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

I have an array of objects, called `specials`, with each object looking like this:

```
{
apr_rate:"",
client_id:"",
disclaimer:",
lease_payment: "",
make:"",
model:"",
name:"",
platform:"",
price:"",
specialOrder:"",
specialStyle: "",
trim:"",
visible:"",
website:"",
year:"",
}
```

I have a loop going through each object in the array and checking to see if the `lease_payment` property is empty. In the case that it is, I splice that particular object out of the array, store it in a new object called `tempObj`, and then push it into a new array called `tempArray`. The reason I am splicing is because I need to order this array of objects first by `lease_payment` in ascending order - when there is no lease payment, it needs to order the remaining objects by `price` in ascending order. However, the ordering of the price needs to happen **after** the ordering of lease. See below:

```
    if (specials[i].lease_payment == "") {
        tempObj = specials.splice(i, 1);
        tempArray.push(tempObj);
    } else {
        // else just assume they're all lease offers and sort by lease payment
        specials.sort(function(a, b) {
            return a.lease_payment - b.lease_payment
        });
    }
```

I then check to see if that new array `tempArray` has 1 object, or multiple. If there is only 1, I immediately push it back into the main `specials` array, where it will be in the back; there is not another object to compare it too and order. If there is more than one object, I reorder those objects based on ascending price, followed by pushing them individually into the `specials` array, since they need to be seen as there own objects. See below.

```
if (tempArray.length == 1) {
    specials.push({tempArray});

} // else just sort the temp array by ascending price, push into main specials later
else if (tempArray.length > 1) {

    tempArray.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a.price - b.price
    });

    // grabs each individual object within temp array and pushes one at a time into main specials
    for (i = 0; i < tempArray.length; i++) {
        specials.push(tempArray[i]);
    }
}
```

What is happening is that in either case, whenever I push an object back into the `specials` array, it being nested within another array, as seen in this screenshot:
[image: ss]

In this instance, two of the 5 specials objects were taken out, sorted, and put back in. However, they are now nested inside an array.

Am I missing something or doing something wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: at first, sort if the for loop ends (thats better for performance)

Comment: you could add some data and the wanted sort outcome in a compact way.

Comment: is `lease_payment` an empty string and a number as string, or just a string, with some letters? please add your data with some examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It happens, because `splice` returns an array. So in line

```
tempObj = specials.splice(i, 1);
```

`tempObj` will be an array an stored a such.
 A solution would be, to write

```
tempObj = specials.splice(i, 1)[0];
```

Comment: Can you explain what exactly adding that `[0]` index at the end is doing?

Comment: Taking a first element of that array.

Comment: Wow, I didn't expect such a simple answer to my problem haha. Looks like that worked! Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Your push repush is a bit complex. I would reorder it like this:

```
 specials.sort((a,b)=>{
   if(a.lease_payment && b.lease_payment){
    return a.lease_payment-b.lease_payment;//sort after lease payment
   }else if(a.lease_payment){
    return 1;//lease payment is already upper
   }else if(b.lease_payment){
    return -1;//swapp
   }else{
    //no leasepayment sort after prize;
   return a.price - b.price;
   }});
```

Or short:

```
specials.sort((a,b)=>a.lease_payment&&b.lease_payment?a.lease_payment-b.lease_payment:a.lease_payment?1:b.leasepayment?-1:a.price-b.price);
```

Comment: Like the way this looks way better than my approach, thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

you make it more readable:

```
var leased = specials.filter(function(e) { return e.lease_payment != ""; }).sort(function(a, b) { return b.price - a.price });

var notLeased = specials.filter(function(e) { return e.lease_payment == ""; }).sort(function(a, b) { return b.price - a.price });

specials = leased.concat(notLeased);
```

Comment: leased ordered after leased!

Answer (score 0):

You could use only a sort function, which sorts first by

- `lease_payment`, asending, assuming the value is a string
- `price`, ascending, assuming value is a number

```js
var data = [{ lease_payment: '', price: 30 }, { lease_payment: '', price: 10 }, { lease_payment: 'a', price: 11 }, { lease_payment: 'b', price: 13 }, { lease_payment: 'c', price: 15 }, { lease_payment: '', price: 8 }];

data.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.lease_payment.localeCompare(b.lease_payment) || a.price - b.price;
});

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Couldnt their be a sorting mistake at the border between sorting after lease_payment and price (upper one has no lease payment but higer price, lower one has no lease payment so the first one returns false, therefore sorted after price?

Comment: op has not supplied any data and no real example of the sort result, all is just guessing.